# Solutions of differential equation given one solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

My thoughts are that
the second and third options are false. About the others, I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x(t) = e^{2t}t$ is a solution, the solutions must take the form
$$x(t) = (t+B)e^{2t},$$
where I substituted $A = 1$ into the general solution
$$x(t) = (At+B)e^{2t}.$$

EDIT: Based upon MathIsFun's comment below, I have revised my thoughts on which are correct expressions. The first and fourth expressions are correct, the second and third are not. So you should tick their boxes accordingly (Blank, Blank, Tick, Blank)

Comment: The expressions in the first and last options are solutions because the equation is linear and homogeneous

Comment: My apologies, you're quite right!

Comment: Why is the third option true?

Answer (score 0):

1. The ODE is linear and homogenous, hence if $x(t)$ is a solution then $\lambda x(t)$ is an other solution for all $\lambda$.
2. The coefficients in the ODE are constant. So, say that $x(t)=te^{2t}$ is a solution means that the associated characteristic equation has a double rout $r=2$. Thus, the general solution is: $x(t)=(a+bt)e^{2t},\qquad \forall a,b\in\mathbb{R}.$